# Adding default layers as dependencies to the yocto meta layer

Tags: yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe, linux-distro, yocto-layer

I am trying to create a yocto custom bsp layer but I want to use the default layers within yocto-oe. This is not working at all.

```
LAYERDEPENDS_custom = "core"
LAYERDEPENDS_custom = "core python3"
#LAYERDEPENDS_custom = "core yocto yocto-bsp openembedded-layer meta-python"


# We have a conf and class directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have recepies-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "    ${LAYERDIR}/recipies-*/*/*.bb \
                ${LAYERDIR}/recipies-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "custom"
BBFILE_PATTERN_custom = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_custom = "15"
LAYERVERSION_custom = "1"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_custom = "dunfell mickledore"

HOSTTOOLS += "xz"
```

The layer check just keeps on failing. I can't add anything other than core. I just want to use the default machine layer for cortexa55 and build the kernel and rootfs here. The machine here uses default cortexa55 tune and defines its own machine which is my custom board 'cx'; at least that's what I was trying to do.
I have tried `python`, `python3`, `meta-python`. Doesn't work.

```
yocto-check-layer meta-custom-unified/ --machines cxg2l
INFO: Detected layers:
INFO: meta-custom-unified: LayerType.BSP, /home/preetam/Workspace/cx-yocto-oe/meta-custom-unified
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on python3 and isn't found.
INFO: 
INFO: Setting up for meta-custom-unified(LayerType.BSP), /home/preetam/Workspace/cx-yocto-oe/meta-custom-unified
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on python3 and isn't found.
INFO: Skipping meta-custom-unified due to missing dependencies.
INFO: 
INFO: Summary of results:
INFO: 
INFO: meta-custom-unified ... SKIPPED (Missing dependencies)
```

I also see a lot of examples online that use the following line:

`LAYERDEPENDS_custom-unified = "core yocto yocto-bsp openembedded-layer meta-python"`

This gives me:

```
INFO: Detected layers:
INFO: meta-custom-unified: LayerType.BSP, /home/preetam/Workspace/cx-yocto-oe/meta-custom-unified
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on meta-python and isn't found.
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on openembedded-layer and isn't found.
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on yocto and isn't found.
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on yocto-bsp and isn't found.
INFO: 
INFO: Setting up for meta-custom-unified(LayerType.BSP), /home/preetam/Workspace/cx-yocto-oe/meta-custom-unified
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on meta-python and isn't found.
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on openembedded-layer and isn't found.
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on yocto and isn't found.
ERROR: Layer meta-custom-unified depends on yocto-bsp and isn't found.
INFO: Skipping meta-custom-unified due to missing dependencies.
INFO: 
INFO: Summary of results:
INFO: 
INFO: meta-custom-unified ... SKIPPED (Missing dependencies)
```

The other question is what does it take for the meta-layer to add `poky/meta`,`poky/yocot-bsp` layers into my layer config selection.
If poky only has `meta` and `meta-yocot-bsp`, where are the other layers coming in from the layer index?